# Cannot run Parcel in my project (Parcel does not create dist with compiled file)

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts, parceljs, parcel

Please help me figure out the problem. I can not understand the essence of the error and how to fix it.

I initialize the project: npm init -y

Install Parcel: npm install --save-dev parcel

I create src directory with an index.html file.

When I run the npx parcel src/index.html command, I get an error:

Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

at Object.open (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules\lmdb\dist\index.cjs:1936:3)
at new LMDBCache (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules@parcel\cache\lib\LMDBCache.js:69:34)
at resolveOptions (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\resolveOptions.js:112:168)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Parcel._init (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:218:27)
at async Parcel.watch (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:315:7)
at async run (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Документи\Projects\Test\node_modules\parcel\lib\cli.js:349:9) {
code: 123 }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by changing the line at node_modules@parcel\core\lib\resolveOptions.js:112:168 to

`let cache = (_initialOptions$cache = initialOptions.cache) !== null && _initialOptions$cache !== void 0 ? _initialOptions$cache : new (_cache().FSCache)(outputFS, cacheDir);`

Basically, I removed the
`outputFS instanceof _fs().NodeFS ? new (_cache().LMDBCache)(cacheDir) :` part of that line. For some unknown reason, there seems to be a problem with LMDBCache and Parcel.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `build` command from `npx parcel src/index.html`:

Update to:

`npx parcel build src/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting /node_modules/ and reinstalling via `npm install` worked for me. I had upgraded my OS and node version recently. That's what was causing the files to not be created, yet the build process was executing without error as if the files were created.